# Problem with pointing an operator with given properties

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

I need help with giving an example of operator.

It should be linear on Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^2$ space, its eigenvalues should be equal to 1 and -1 and its norm should be bigger than $N$ for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$.

I only know that it should be a matrix and if such matrix would be diagonal, then its norm ought to be maximum from expressions on the diagonal. Anyway it doesn't help me a lot.

Comment: There are different matrix norms ; It looks you consider the so-called "spectral norm" ; how can this norm be arbitrarily large ?...

Comment: What about the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & N\\0& -1\end{bmatrix}$? Its norm is larger than the given number $N$.

Comment: @Mark it seems reasonable. But how are we evaluating norm in this case?

Comment: @Novice I assume you mean the spectral norm here. The vector $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\1\end{bmatrix}$ is a unit vector, and $\begin{bmatrix}1 & N\\0& -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}N\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, which is a vector with norm larger than $N$. Thus $||A||=\max_{||x||=1} ||Ax||>N$.

Comment: @Mark : Please make this an answer. It's nice, clean, and helps to site.